# How to code strings containing numbers in codio (python)

Tags: python, string, int

```py
# Input from the command line
# converted to an integer
import sys
number1 = int(sys.argv[1])
number2 = int(sys.argv[2])

# Your code goes here 

Ive tried:

newString = '123' + str(456)
print(newString)

newString = '123' + '456'
print(newString)

newString = '123' + str(number2)
print(newString)

newString = (number1 + number2)
print(newString)
```

I either get 
Program Output

```
Program Failed for Input: 0 0
Expected Output: 00
Your Program Output: 123456

Your output was incorrect. Try again.

OR

Program Output

Program Failed for Input: 123 456
Expected Output: 123456
Your Program Output: 579

Your output was incorrect. Try again.
```

Im suppose to be getting Input 123 456 Output 123456

Comment: Why do you convert the input to ``int``? Judging by the desired output, you need to concatenate strings. Take note that it is very difficult to provide help without knowing what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I am suppose to combine the two inputs into 1 string. But not add them together. Which is what keeps happening.

Comment: `print(sys.argv[1] + sys.argv[2])` -> this should be sufficient.

Comment: Then why are you converting the input to integers?

Comment: Because I was confusing the example with the problem itself. I just got it.

Answer (score 0):

> Im suppose to be getting Input 123 456 Output 123456

I think you're confusing the one example problem given with the general solution.

You're supposed to only use the number1 and number2 variables, not literally 123 and 456

The closest answer you have is this, but instead of 123, use `number1` in a way that produces the expected result

```
newString = '123' + str(number2)
print(newString)
```

Comment: newString = str(number1) + str(number2)